# Может ли результат хеширования быть одинаковым при разных вводных данных?

Tags: хеширование

Для примера возьмем подобную строку, которую нужно зашифровать. "1 asdfghj". Первая переменная цифра (чтобы легко было подобрать), затем строка из допустим 8 символов. При хешировании выдало результат допустим assdfsfsfasffsagg.Нужно найти и число и 7-ми значную строку, у которой будет результат хеширования как и у первой.

Comment: [Коллизия хеш-функции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8).

Comment: [Радужная таблица](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Радужная_таблица)

Comment: Да, могу совпадать. При хорошей хеширующей функции подбор, мягко говоря, очень твудоемок и долог. Где обещанный миллион?

Comment: В Питоне на целых числах можно поместить все элементы хеш-таблицы (хеш-сета) в одну корзину. То есть у них всех будет одинаковый хеш (по модулю размера таблицы). Заметно снаружи по падению производительности при работе с этим конкретным контейнером. Тоже хочу миллион. Можно полмиллиона, так как тут числа, не строки.

Comment: `r = range(0, 10**22, 2305843009213693951)`, `len(r)` -> `4337`, `set(map(hash, r))` -> `{0}`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy не очень понял что конкретно делает код выше

Comment: Количество хешей ограничено. Количество входных строк ‐ нет. Вывод очевиден.

Comment: @Эникейщик т.е. можно найти больше одного значения, хеш которого будет совпадать?

Comment: Разумеется, можно.

Comment: @Эникейщик можешь примерно сказать по времени сколько это может занять для python в одном потоке? Буду очень благодарен

Comment: В зависимости от входных данных и используемой хеш-функции время может варьироваться от долей секунды до многих триллионов лет.

Comment: Что "это"?.....

Comment: "Код выше" предявляет 4337 различных чисел, которые имеют один и тот же хеш - 0.